# Disqualified Lead when first or last name is Test

Tags: apex, trigger

I am getting an Expression cannot be assigned error. My logic is to check if the characters of either first or last name is exactly 4 letters to prevent false positives like Beta Tester.

```
trigger LeadDisqualification on Lead (before insert, before update) {

    //Logic - check to see if first or last name contains Test and that first or last name length is 4.
    for (Lead myLead : Trigger.new) {
        if (myLead.FirstName == 'test' && myLead.FirstName.length() = 4 || myLead.LastName == 'test' && myLead.LastName.length() = 4) {
            mylead.Status = 'Disqualified';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two of your `if` conditions have `=`, assignment, rather than `==`, which compares for equality. You can't assign to a function result, so you get this syntax error.

Your length checks are redundant and can be removed, since you are already checking for string equality. While string equality is case-insensitive in Apex, it is *not* a substring match - the entire string must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `==` to check for equality, as `=` is for assignment. Note that `'Test' == 'Tester'` will always return false. To find a partial match, you'd have to intentionally call a method that does so, like String.containsIgnoreCase. There's no need to check the length.

Whenever you want to call a method on an object, always make sure it's not null first when using user supplied data; your trigger would actually fail if FirstName were null.

Finally, if you want to check for "first name equals test or last name equals test," you need to use `||` (or). Your current attempt reads "first name equals test and last name equals test," meaning it only triggers when both first name **and** last name are **both** "test", not when only one of them is "test."